# unw_graph class (unweighted graph)

Tags: c++, template, graph, stl

Here is my new STL-like implementation of an unweighted graph. Could you please tell me what member functions I should include in my library?

**unweighted_graph.hpp**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

#ifndef __UNWEIGHTED_GRAPH_HPP
#define __UNWEIGHTED_GRAPH_HPP

namespace lemon {
  template< class T, bool dir >
  class unw_graph {
  private:
    map< T, set< T > > adj;
    int vcnt;
    int ecnt;
  public:
    typedef typename map< T, set< T > >::iterator vertex_iterator;
    typedef typename map< T, set< T > >::const_iterator vertex_const_iterator;
    typedef typename set< T >::iterator link_iterator;
    typedef typename set< T >::const_iterator link_const_iterator;
    typedef pair< T, T > link_type;
    typedef size_t size_type;

    vertex_iterator begin() { return adj.begin(); }
    vertex_const_iterator begin() const { return adj.begin(); }

    vertex_iterator end() { return adj.end(); }
    vertex_const_iterator end() const { return adj.end(); }

    unw_graph( ) : adj( map< T, set< T > >() ), vcnt( 0 ), ecnt( 0 ) {}

    void insert_vertex( const T& init ) {
      if( adj.find( init )!=adj.end() ) return;
      else {
        adj.insert( make_pair( init, set< T >() ) );
        vcnt++;
      }
    }

    void insert_link( const pair< T, T > &e ) {
      insert_vertex( e.first );
      insert_vertex( e.second );
      if( adj[ e.first ].find( e.second ) == adj[ e.first ].end() ) {
        adj[ e.first ].insert( e.second );
        ecnt++;
      }
      if( !dir ) {
        if( adj[ e.second ].find( e.first ) == adj[ e.second ].end() ) {
          adj[ e.second ].insert( e.first );
        }
      }
    }

    unw_graph( const vector< pair< T, T > > &edge_list ) : adj( map< T, set< T > >() ), vcnt( 0 ), ecnt( 0 ) {
      typename vector< pair< T, T > >::iterator it;
      for( it=edge_list.begin(); it!=edge_list.end(); ++it ) {
        insert_link( *it );
      }
    }

    void erase_link( const pair< T, T > &e ) {
      if( adj.find( e.first ) == adj.end() || adj.find( e.second ) == adj.end() ) return;
      typename set< T >::iterator it=adj[ e.first ].find( e.second );
      if( it!=adj[ e.first ].end() ) {
        adj[ e.first ].erase( it );
        ecnt--;
      }
      if( !dir ) {
        it=adj[ e.second ].find( e.first );
        if( it!=adj[ e.second ].end() ) {
          adj[ e.second ].erase( it );
        }
      }
    }

    typename map< T, set< T > >::iterator find_vertex( const T& vr ) {
      return adj.find( vr );
    }
    typename map< T, set< T > >::const_iterator find_vertex( const T& vr ) const {
      return adj.find( vr );
    }

    bool connection( const pair< T, T > &e ) {
      if( adj.find( e.first ) == adj.end() || adj.find( e.second ) == adj.end() ) return false;
      else return adj[ e.first ].find( e.second ) != adj[ e.first ].end();
    }

    set< T >& operator[] ( T idx ) {
      return adj[ idx ];
    }
    const set< T >& operator[] ( T idx ) const {
      return adj[ idx ];
    }

    size_t vertices() const { return vcnt; }
    size_t links() const { return ecnt; }
    bool directed() const { return dir; }
  };
}

#endif
```

**test1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "unweighted_graph.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  freopen( "file.in", "r", stdin );

  lemon::unw_graph< string, false > g;
  int Ec;
  cin >> Ec;

  while( Ec-- ) {
    string a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    g.insert_link( make_pair( a, b ) );
  }

  cout << g.vertices() << " " << g.links() << endl;
  lemon::unw_graph< string, false >::vertex_iterator i;
  for( i=g.begin(); i!=g.end(); ++i ) {
    cout << i->first << ": ";
    lemon::unw_graph< string, false >::link_iterator j;
    for( j=i->second.begin(); j!=i->second.end(); ++j ) {
      cout << *j << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  g.erase_link( make_pair( "athens", "lamia" ) );

  cout << g.vertices() << " " << g.links() << endl;
  for( i=g.begin(); i!=g.end(); ++i ) {
    cout << i->first << ": ";
    lemon::unw_graph< string, false >::link_iterator j;
    for( j=i->second.begin(); j!=i->second.end(); ++j ) {
      cout << *j << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**test2.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "unweighted_graph.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  freopen( "file2.in", "r", stdin );

  lemon::unw_graph< int, true > g;
  int N,M;
  cin >> N >> M;

  for( int i=0; i<N; ++i ) {
    g.insert_vertex( i+1 );
  }

  while( M-- ) {
    int from,to;
    cin >> from >> to;
    g.insert_link( make_pair( from, to ) );
  }

  for( int i=1; i<=N; ++i ) {
    cout << i << ": ";
    lemon::unw_graph< int, false >::link_iterator j;
    for( j=g[ i ].begin(); j!=g[ i ].end(); ++j ) {
      cout << *j << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### The big pain points:

1. Put the include guards first.
   No point in re-including header files if you don't need to
2. Never use `using namespace std;` in a header file.
   Anybody that includes your code now has all the standard stuff pushed into global namespace where it can cause huge problems in other peoples code.
   I would even say never use this in your normal source files (but others think that is a bit far (I don't)). If you must import stuff keep it as confined as possable and only import what you need `using std::cout;` etc.. (still don't do that in global scope in a header file).
3. Double underscore in an identifier is reserved.
   DON'T DO IT WILL BREAK SOMETHING WHEN YOU LEAST EXPECT.

#### Interface design

Your graph looks like it wants to be treated as a container. Thus it is probably a good idea to make its types look like a standard container. So make the types of the iterators conform. begin() and end() shoud return iterator or const_iterator

```
typedef typename map< T, set< T > >::iterator vertex_iterator;
typedef typename map< T, set< T > >::const_iterator vertex_const_iterator;
```

Change too:

```
typedef typename std::map<T, std::set<T> >   Store;
typedef typename Store::iterator             iterator;
typedef typename Store::const_iterator       const_iterator;

// Now if the type changes you only need to change it in one place.
```

#### Misunderstanding of basic std::map/std::set

```
void insert_vertex( const T& init ) {
  if( adj.find( init )!=adj.end() ) return;
  else {
    adj.insert( make_pair( init, set< T >() ) );
    vcnt++;
  }
}
```

This is all wasted code. If the map does not contain an element then then operator[] will auto insert a default node using the default constructor for the value type (which in this case is the empty set).

```
void insert_vertex( const T& init )
{
    adj[init];
    vcnt = adj.size();  // which brings us to the question of why vcnt
                        // is a separate member. When it is just the size of adj?
}
```

I would say the same here for the set.

```
  if( adj[ e.first ].find( e.second ) == adj[ e.first ].end() ) {
    adj[ e.first ].insert( e.second );
    ecnt++;
  }
```

The only reason here you actually need the test is because you need to decide weather to increment `ecnt`. I would just always insert (sets don't have multiple values the same so an insert of a value that already exists does nothing).

```
  if (adj[e.first].insert(e.second).second)
  {   ++ecnt;
  }
  // The result of an insert is a std::pair<iterator,bool>
  // Where the iterator points at the value inserted
  // And the bool indicates weather the insert worked (if there already exists
  // a value then it will fail).
```

Answer (score 2):

Loki Astari's review is good, but I wanted to add a point or two to some future things you might want to address. `std::map` (and `std::set`) take a few extra parameters in their template arguments:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Compare = std::less<Key>, typename Allocator>
class map
{ 
   //...
};
```

`Allocators` are a bit tricky, so we'll ignore that for now. However, you should definitely look at including a `Compare` parameter for your graph. This will allow users to utilize their own classes for your template parameter `T`. For example:

```
struct some_class
{
    int i;
}

struct sc_compare
{
    bool operator()(const some_class& s1, const some_class& s2) 
    { 
        return s1.i < s2.i; 
    }
};
```

Then users can utilize `some_class` as verticies: `lemon::unw_graph<some_class, false, sc_compare>`.